# c++ подключение файлов

Tags: c++, header

Как подключить файл если его название записано в переменной?

Это нужно для того чтобы сделать ResourcePack

Вот код:

```
#define pathToSettingsResourcePack = "../"+resourcePack+"/SettingsResourcePack.hpp"
#include pathToSettingsResourcePack
```

P.S. Тут вызывается ошибка

Comment: Этого сделать нельзя, так как препроцессор не работает с переменными.

Comment: @Πανμέτρονάριστον У препроцессора есть макросы, например в `#define HDR "sysv.h"` препроцессорный токен `HDR` является именем макроса, препроцессор будет заменять этот токен на заданную подстановочную последовательность.

Comment: @Πανμέτρονάριστον Так это будет уже другой вопрос...

Comment: Что такое `resourcePack`? Что это за "переменная"? Что означает слово "переменная" в данном случае?

Comment: Ошибка не в resourcPack(вроде бы) ну я а если в ней, то это переменная, да

Comment: И ДА, ВОПРОС ЗАКРЫТ, Я РЕШИЛ ПО-ДРУГОМУ

Answer (score 0):

Вот такой способ есть:

```
#if PATH == FIRST
    #define HDR "../catalog-1/SettingsResourcePack.hpp"
#elif PATH == SECOND
    #define HDR "../catalog-2/SettingsResourcePack.hpp"
#elif PATH == THIRD
    #define HDR "../catalog-3/SettingsResourcePack.hpp"
#else
    #define HDR "../catalog-4/SettingsResourcePack.hpp"
#endif
#include HDR
```

Comment: просто ошибка заключается в том, что я подключаю файл при помощи переменной, а ты так же

Comment: всм неправильно?

Comment: где они вложенные?

Comment: кавычка открывается, закрывается, переменная, кавычка открывается, закрывается. Где вложенность?

Comment: update: ты решил проблему статически, а надо динамически

Comment: @Lofectr., а динамически не получится. Да и зачем? C++ - компилируемый, а не интерпретируемый язык.

Comment: если пользователь захочет создать ресурс-пак он будет заходить в код и перекомпилировать его?

Comment: @Lofectr., в ключах компилятора есть `-D`. Вы можете использовать его для передачи макросов в препроцессор. Например, можете написать в коде -- `#include STDIO` и вызвать компилятор вот так -- `gcc -DSTDIO='<stdio.h>' ...` В результата при компиляции подключится файл `#include <stdio.h>`

Comment: @Lofectr., ну так один фиг, это статически, просто не из файла, а из консоли или make-файла.

Comment: мне надо чтобы этот файл был записан в другом файле(который я успешно подключил) в виде переменной или макроса